# EC2 instance w/ 2 ENI (public / private) can not communicate w/ another EC2 instance on private subnet

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am a newby in AWS but multiple decades of networking experience.

I have a simple design with 1 VPC having 1 public subnet (PUBSUB) and 1 private subnet (PRIVSUB) (well actually 2 each if counting the AZ). Obviously, both subnets are part of the VPC subnet.

I have an EC2 instance (EC2-A) w/ 2 ENI, 1 for each subnets (eth0 for PUBSUB and eth1 for PRIVSUB).
Another EC2 instance (EWC2-B) w/ 1 ENI, connected to PRIVSUB (eth0).

Security groups (more than 1) allows ICMP, ICMP6, SSH on the inbound side. The outbound side is All, All and 0.0.0.0/0 (and ::/0).

I can not ping nor initiate SSH from EC2-A to EC2-B. However, the ARP table does show EC2-B's MAC address for eth1 (as expected).

EC2-A's IP route table shows the correct route for PRIVSUB, using eth1 (also as it should).

So, from a VM perspective all is good in both instances. If I was running this in KVM or even physical machine I am certain it would work.

Now, the Reachability Analyzer tells a very different story. For the path from EC2-A to EC2-B, it shows that the path is going through the router via PUBSUB (eth0), which the OS is NOT agreeing with.

If I force the OS to agree with the Reachability Analyzer by manually removing the IP address on eth1 then all is working. I can ping and log in EC2-B.

I am bit confused. Is an EC2 w/ 2 ENI supposed to work, i.e. access a resource directly attached to the 2nd ENI? If not then what is the purpose of supporting 2 ENI?